# Converting unsigned to double to unsigned without loss of precision

Tags: c, floating-point, c99, ieee-754, floating-point-conversion

Will an integer value converted to a floating-point value and back again be the same as the original integer value?

For example:

```
unsigned x = 42;
double y = x;
unsigned z = y;
```

Assuming the compiler doesn't optimize out the floating-point conversion, will `x == z` always evaluate as **true**?

I suspect that any representation error in the floating-point conversion will always be an *increase* in value. Therefore, when the floating-point value is converted back to an integer value, the value is *truncated* which always results in the original integer value.

Is my assumption correct?

Comment: No, a conversion will not always keep the same value or increase it. If the source value is exactly representable, there is no error. If the source value is not exactly representable, it is rounded to the **nearest** representable value (in the usual default rounding mode), with ties favoring the value with zero in the least significand bit of its significand (fraction portion of the floating-point format). So rounding will be upward sometimes and downward sometimes.

Comment: @EricPostpischil So for integers greater than 2**53, it may be the case that the value is rounded downward, such that when converted back to an integer, the truncated value is less than the original (i.e. `x == z` possibly results in `0` for integers greater than 2**53)?

Comment: Yes, Pascal Cuoq gave an example, 2**53+1, in [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20148030/298225). Note that when the value is converted back to an integer, it is not truncated, because it is still an integer.  E.g., converting 2**53+1 to `double` yields 2**53.  Converting that back to a 64-bit integer format yields 2**53. This second conversion is exact; it does not truncate or round, because the value is exactly representable in the new destination format (64-bit integer).

Comment: It is also possible that the conversion of a large integer to double rounds up, resulting in a final value larger than the original. The commonest double rounding mode, round to nearest with ties go to even, is designed to round up and down equally often.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming IEEE 754 double-precision format for `double`, the expression `x == z` will evaluate to `1` for all values of `x` up to 2<sup>53</sup>. If your compiler offers 32-bit `unsigned int`, for instance, this means for all possible values of `x`.

You have edited your question to ask about the conversion from integer to float. In most C implementations, this conversion rounds according to the FPU rounding mode, which is by default round-to-nearest-even. There is an asymmetry with the conversion from float to integer there (as you point out, the conversion from float to int always truncates).

However, any error in the conversion from integer to float would not mean that you get a fractional part where there was none, but that you get the wrong integer altogether. For instance the integer 2<sup>53</sup>+1 is converted to the `double` that represents 2<sup>53</sup>. For this reason it would not help that the conversion from float to integer truncates even if the conversion from float to integer always rounded up.

The rounding error in the conversion from integer to float can be larger than one: the integer `5555555555555555555`, when converted to `double`, is rounded to `5555555555555555328`, which happens to be have a simpler representation in binary than the former. Half the times, the rounding goes upward: for instance `5555555555555555855` is rounded to `5555555555555556352`.

Comment: Supported by C 2011 (N1570) 6.3.1.4 2: “When a value of integer type is converted to a real floating type, if the value being converted can be represented exactly in the new type, it is unchanged.” 1: “When a finite value of real floating type is converted to an integer type other than **_Bool**, the fractional part is discarded (i.e., the value is truncated toward zero).”

Comment: @chux:  2**54-1 has 54 bits.  E.g., 2**4-1 is binary 1111.

Comment: @chux: 2**1-1 is binary 1; it has 1 bit. 2**2-1 is binary 11; it has 2 bits. 2**3-1 is binary 111; it has 3 bits. 2**4-1 is binary 1111; it has 4 bits. 2**5-1 is binary 11111; it has 5 bits… 2**54-1 has 54 bits. In 2**54-1, the bit in every position from the 2**53 position to the 2**0 position is 1. That is 54 positions.

Comment: @PascalCuoq I'm a bit confused when you mention FPU rounding mode; I thought this only applied to the `nearbyint` function. Are you saying that some implementations do not truncate non-integer floating-point values, but rather use the current FPU rounding mode when initializing an `int` with a `float` variable?

Comment: @VilhelmGray The conversion from float to int always truncate: this is what the standard says and that's the end of the story. The conversion from int to float produces exactly the same value when the value is exactly representable (see the standard quote that Eric dug up), and an implementation-defined choice of the upper value or the lower value when the integer value to convert is not exactly representable in the destination type. Most C implementations define the choice to be: “according to what the FPU rounding mode is currently set to”.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil  I see the error of my ways.  The largest exactly convertible number is +power(2,53), a 54 bit number (and the only positive 54 bit number that works continuous with others).  Smallest is -power(2,53).  Thus providing a fictitious int54_t or uint53_t exact conversion.

Answer (score 2):

Any integer up to 2<sup>53</sup> has an exact representation as a double-precision floating-point number if `double` follows IEEE-754 (as your tag suggests). So, assuming `int` is 32-bit, yes, you can convert an `unsigned` to `double` without loss of precision.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that your floating point double precision type is a 64 bit IEEE754 type. (The C standard does not insist on this but it's what you have tagged).

It depends on the size of your `unsigned int`. If it's 32 bit then yes, if 64 bit then not necessarily. (The cutoff is on the 53rd bit: 2<sup>53</sup> + 1 is the smallest positive number cannot be represented precisely in an IEEE floating point `double`.).

On 32 bit platforms, the answer is always yes.

On 64 bit platforms it depends on the compiler. In LP64 and LLP64, `unsigned int` is 32 bit but in ILP64 it is 64 bit. (Note that Win64 uses LLP64 which *also* sets `long` at 32 bit as well).